# Finding common elements from lists in list

Tags: python

I have a list that includes more lists (this is how it looks https://pastebin.com/BW4B9gfa). The number of lists is not constant. I need to create another list that contains only elements that are in all lists in the main list.
I made something like this as a prototype but it doesn't work:

```
def common_elements(list_of_lists):
    lists = list_of_lists
    common = lists[0].intersection(lists[1].intersection(lists[2].intersection(lists[3].intersection(lists[4].intersection(lists[5])))))
return common
```

I see too something like this:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [2,4,7,8]
commonalities = set(A) - (set(A) - set(B))
```

but I don't know how to use it with bigger number of lists.

Comment: What's the point of doing `lists = list_of_lists`? Why don't you just do `def common_elements(lists):`?

Comment: yes ur right, thats no make sense. I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the first list to a set so you can use the `intersection()` method.

Use a loop rather than hard-coding all the indexes of the list elements.

```
def common_elements(lists):
    if len(lists) == 0:
        return []

    common = set(lists[0])
    for l in lists[1:]:
        common = common.intersection(l)

    return list(common)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do if you have a list of sets, to get a list of sets just do (lists = [set(list) for list in lists]).

```
lists[0].intersection(*lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `functools.reduce()`:

```
from functools import reduce

items = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7, 9]]
eggs = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), items)
print(eggs)
```

output:

```
{1, 4}
```

If you want to get intermediate results, you can use `itertools.accumulate()`

```
from itertools import accumulate

items = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7, 9]]
eggs = list(accumulate(items, func = lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y)))
print(eggs)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 5], {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}]
```